# What is a good database design for complaint-moderator processes

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a question answer site. I need to design some tables of complaint-moderator process. In this process, any user can complain about question, moderator will can accept the complaints when number of specific type of complaints about a question reached to a certain amount.

**In detail:**

A user asks a question. Then, another user read this question, wants to flag a type of complaint.

When this user flags a question with any type of complaint, it will be saved. Flags have type property(ComplaintA, ComplaintB, ModeratorAttention,..).

Moderators can see flags about any question. If number of ComplaintA type flags about a question reaches a certain amount(a constant like 10), moderator will accept these flags.

Then, these flags of the same type will be saved with a message which will be seen under question with flaggers(ProcessType is ComplaintsAccepted).

Then, when user who asked the question can send a flag with message to moderator attention after fixing his question. The moderator can accept resolution of Complaint if the correction is satisfactory(ProcessType is ResolutionAccepted).

**The details of my draft design:**

```
Users (Table of Sql Membership Provider)
-----
- UserId
- Password
- Email
-...

Questions
---------
- QuestionId
- ...

Flags
----------
- FlagId
- QuestionId
- FlaggerId --> Flagger is a user
- FlagType --> ComplaintA, ComplaintB, ModeratorAttention
- FlagMessage

ModeratorProcesses
------------------
- ProcessId
- ProcessMessage
- QuestionId
- FlagType
- ProcessType   --> ComplaintAccepted / ResolutionAccepted / DeleteAccepted
- ModeratorId   --> Moderator is a user
- DateOfProcess
```

**Table Relations:**
ModeratorProcesses - 1:m - Flags - n:1 - Questions

Is this a good database design for this processes?

Comment: Before you can properly design any database, you have to write down, in English or your native language, all of the relationships between your data types.  So far, you've written "any user can complain about question, moderator will can accept the complaints when number of specific type of complaints about a question reached to a certain amount".  Write them all down.

Comment: I tried to write down.

Comment: If you can't write the relationships down, you can't design a database.  You don't even understand the problem you're trying to solve yet.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can you elaborate what you mean with "relationships" ?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't think you start with relationship. Instead you start with entities first before relationship. And looking at his design it is obvious that he is on the right path not to mentioned that his tables implied relationships already with PK and FK identified.

Comment: @serefbilge your processId And ComplaintID is it a composite primary key in your compalintsaccepted table?

Comment: One process to multiple complaints of same type related one question

Comment: But your relationshipn is between ModeratorProcess and ComplaintsAccepted not Complaints and it looks like 1-to-1 to me.

Comment: @Edper I tried to correct, see my question.

Comment: I think that's the right 1:m relationship now than awhile ago whic is 1:1. Now where is your user Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good database design for this process?

Your database design appears to match your requirements.

Entity names are usually singular, not plural.  User, Question, Flag, ModeratorProcess.

In the Flag entity, rather than call the column FlaggerId, call the column UserId.  That way, the foreign key relationship is obvious.  Make the same change of ModeratorId to UserId in the ModeratorProcess entity.  Your FlagType and ProcessType comments are fine, as they explain the column.

Rather than DateOfProcess in the ModeratorProcess entity, call it ProcessTimestamp.  That should be a date / time field.  You'll probably want a timestamp field in the Flag table.